# Android Studio Gradle Sync Issue: Red Variable Names Everywhere

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, ide, android-studio-3.0

I have a strange problem with my IDE. Android Studio compiles and builds my app correctly, but my source code is littered with red variables like you see below:
[image]

I'm not sure how to fix the issue; the usual techniques of clean/rebuilds and invalidating caches and restarting haven't worked. I've also tried deleting the .idea folder and reinstalling Android Studio. Deleting the project and cloning it fresh from version control doesn't fix the issue either.

What's also strange is that while I can run the app successfully, this Android Studio error prevents debugging (my break points are never hit even though the code is executing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fix the issue.

In my app's gradle.build I removed one of the many libraries that was showing up as unknown (red) in a given classes' imports. After removing deleting the import I ran a clean in Android Studio, then re-added the gradle import and viola: no more red variables!

I think the same the could be accomplished with a gradle refresh( `gradle build --refresh-dependencies`) and potentially removing an import beforehand and then readding it.

Answer (score 0):

did you import android studio setting file from previous one ?

Comment: I believe so, how can I check?

Comment: I mean you shouldn't. I remember faced same issue before then reinstall/update the new android studio version without import previous setting and IDE back to normal